# How to trim of those empty elements in Array?

Tags: scala

I've got any `Array[Object]`

```
Array(obj1, (), (), obj2, (), obj3, (), (), obj4)
```

How can clear those empty elements and get it as

```
Array(obj1, obj2,  obj3, obj4)
```

Comment: What is `()`? Is it a `null` or some dummy object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myArray filter (e => e != ())
```

Comment: Or just `myArray.filter(_ != ())`

Comment: @serejja: Golfed! :P Thanks, yeah, that's better, for such a nonce usage